# CascadingDropDown onchange handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, cascadingdropdown

Is it possible to use an jQuery `change()` handler with an ASP.NET AJAX CascadingDropDown? I'd like to change the value of another dropdown on the page, which is unrelated to the cascading behavior. The following never executes:

```
$('#<%= ddlFromCompetition.ClientID %>').change(function() {
  $('#<%= ddlToCompetition.ClientID %>').value = $('#<%= ddlFromCompetition.ClientID %>').value;
});
```

which produces the following at runtime:

```
$('#ctl00_c1_ddlFromCompetition').change(function() {
  $('#ctl00_c1_ddlToCompetition').value = $('#ctl00_c1_ddlFromCompetition').value;
});
```